# How to sort rows in alphabetical order across columns in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula, alphabetical

Let's say I have `Column A` with some names followed by some data in `Column B` and `Column C`

Similarly, I have `Column D` with some names followed by some data in `Column E` and `Column F`.

I would like to **sort the rows in alphabetical order** keeping certain columns (in this case A and D) as their alphabetical guides.

Later on, if I add more columns with more names and data, I would want the function/formula to account for that addition to the list as well.

*For Example:*

```
    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 Albert  | ....... | ....... | Albert  | ....... | .......
 Charlie | ....... | ....... | Brian   | ....... | .......
         |         |         | David   | ....... | .......
```

*Expected Result:*

Albert would show in the same row as he is repeated in columns A and D.
Brian, Charlie and David would show in different rows as their name is not repeated across columns.

Is there a way to do it?

```
    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |    E    |    F
---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 Albert  | ....... | ....... | Albert  | ....... | .......
         |         |         | Brian   | ....... | .......
 Charlie | ......  |......   |         |         |  
         |         |         | David   | ......  | ........
```

^^ As you notice there are blank rows in the columns in which a name isn't shown in the list.

Comment: Why wouldn't you combine column A and D in this case and then sort the table on column A?

Comment: What Excel version do you have? are you open to power query or vba solution?

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do what you want. Please try it. Note that you can set the main parameters in the enumeration at the top of the code.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                            ' Worksheet navigation: modify as appropriate
    ' 03 Mar 2019
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2             ' assuming 1 caption row: change as appropriate
    NwsSortClm1 = 1                 ' First name column to sort (1 = A)
    NwsSortClm2 = 4                 ' 4 = D
    NwsDataClms = 2                 ' number of data columns next to sort columns
End Enum

Sub SortNames()
    ' 03 Mar 2019

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr(1) As Variant
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p As Long                           ' priority

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook                   ' change as appropriate: better to define Wb by name
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' change tab name as appropriate
    Ws.Copy After:=Ws
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    C = NwsSortClm1
    For i = 0 To 1                          ' corresponds to LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        With Ws
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, C), _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, C + NwsDataClms).End(xlUp))
            With .Sort.SortFields
                .Clear
                .Add Key:=Rng.Columns(1), _
                     SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                     Order:=xlAscending, _
                     DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            End With
            With .Sort
                .SetRange Rng
                .Header = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            Arr(i) = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, C), _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, C + NwsDataClms).End(xlUp)).Value
        End With
        C = NwsSortClm2
    Next i

    R = NwsFirstDataRow
    With Ws
        Do While Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm1).Value) And _
                 Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm2).Value) > 0
            p = StrComp(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm1).Value, _
                        .Cells(R, NwsSortClm2).Value, _
                        vbTextCompare)          ' not case sensitive !
            If p Then
                C = IIf(p < 0, NwsSortClm2, NwsSortClm1)
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, C), .Cells(R, C + NwsDataClms))
                Rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End If
            R = R + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code should be installed om a standard code module. The procedure to run is called *SortNames*.

For testing purposes create a short version of your actual data, say 5 to 8 rows only. Create at least 3 versions of this test sheet. One with both SortColumns of equal length and one each where either of the SortColumns is longer. Observe that it should make a difference whether one SortColumn has several entries at the end after the other SortColumn is complete. Remember to change the tab name in `Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")` before test runs.

Add this code below the double line *Do While Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm1).Value) And _
                 Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm2).Value) > 0*

```
Debug.Print .Cells(R, NwsSortClm1).Value, Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm1).Value), _
                    .Cells(R, NwsSortClm2).Value, Len(.Cells(R, NwsSortClm2).Value)
```

and add a break point to it. To add a break point click on the grey, vertical bar to the left of the code window. Two brown points will appear there and the two lines will be highlighted brown. (To remove the break point click the brown points.) Now, when you place the cursor anywhere in the procedure *SortNames* and press F5 the code will run up to the break point and stop. When stopped all values are in memory and you can query them to make sure they are as expected.

The first part of the test is to run the code above the break point. It creates a copy of the sheet and sorts both columns. You will be able to see the progress. If there is any irregularity so far more tests have to be done on the first half of the code. If not, press F5 again. Each time you press F5 one loop of the code will run until the break point is hit again. Instead of pressing F5 you can press F8 to run only one line of code and stop.

In the loop the `Debug.Print` instruction will be carried out first. You can point the cursor at `R`and the current row number will be shown next to the cursor. The `Debug.Print` instructions will print the current values of the two SortColumns and the length (number of characters) of these strings to the Immediate Window (below the code window panel). The code continues looping while both cells have a value the length of which is greater than zero. If, by reason of a logical error, this never happens the loop would continue ad infinitum which isn't the intention.

To stop the test, remove the break point and press F5 or press the little square above the *Run* command in the top command bar which has "Reset" as a control tip text.

Comment: I am on Office 2016.  Excuse my ignorance, but where do I install this code?

Comment: The main goal of this chart would be to easily find missing items from previous columns to the new columns.  

In the example above you can see that Albert made it to column A and D, but Charlie failed to make it to the new list.

This way I can see Charlie is missing from column D and I can track him back to his last column activity. 

This would be a dynamic ever growing chart in which I could track activity records very quickly.

Comment: I tried to run the macros and it didn't work.  Maybe I need to adjust some range in it.   The actual chart that I have has some heading and the real values to sort starts at A4 followed by data until I4, then next set of values starts at J4 followed by data until R4... then I will keep adding more and more data using the same spacing.

Comment: It seems you got it installed but "doesn't work" is too broad to be helpful. If your data start in A4 then `NwsFirstDataRow = 4` and `NwsSortClm1 = 1` (unchanged). Since you have 8 data columns B:I, `NwsDataClms = 8` and  `NwsSortClm2 = 10`. Note that the code creates a sorted copy of the original data, not touching the latter.

Comment: So I change the range to match the chart.  the excel file got stuck and ran excel ran my CPU up to 97% on just excel.  After force closing excel the rest of my CPU went to 8% total.

Comment: Since you say "the Excel got stuck" it seems likely that the loop doesn't find an end. I added testing instructions to my answer which will enable you to find the condition, created by the nature of the data, when this happens. By design the loop should end when only one of the two SortColumns has a value in it. In my tests it did but I tested with fake and reduced data and I didn't test all 9 variations that might occur. You also made changes to the parameters. You will find out by watching what is printed at the break point.

Comment: I try to add the debug code and it kept giving different errors like compile error for example.... worth to say I never coded before.

Comment: On the other hand, with adjusted setting on the range and adjusted chart to match the setting, it isn't getting stuck in excel anymore, instead, the names under column  J got rearrange without any sort of alphabetical order and there are no spaces for any missing previous names.  The next set of columns with their range of values were column S and column AB were untouched.

Comment: What are the values you assigned to the Nws enumeration? Set a break point as described, run until the break. A copy of the sheet should have been created and both SortColumns sorted. Don't continue after the stop if this isn't the case.

Comment: I have 'NwsFirstDataRow = 4'  ,  'NwsSortClm1 = 1' . 'NwsSortClm2 = 8' , 'NwsDataClms = 10' ....  The data to sort starts at A4 with heading at A3, followed by 8 more columns of data which belongs to column A. Then the next set of columns starting at J4 with names followed by 8 more columns of data finishing at R4.... then it repeats with more columns of data in the same order.

Comment: I changed the code to "NwsSortClm2 = 10" and "NwsDataClms = 8".  It seems like it flip the data of rows 3 and 4 (3 is the heading and 4 is the data) from columns A through I.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2uqCs4kkrc&t=3s)   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2uqCs4kkrc&t=3s

Comment: I'm on a business trip which accounts both for my slow response and the circumstance that I have access to YouTube which I normally don't. Please try to get a copy of your test workbook to me. That will be easier this week than next because I have restricted access to some international sites when I'm at home. For the moment I can't figure out why rows 3 and 4 would be flipped. However, columns to the right of (NwsSortClm2 + NwsDataClms) will be dislocated by the code. They aren't provided for because your question didn't mention their existence. I suggest to ignore them for the moment.

Comment: Note that the `Do While Len(...` line of syntax is broken over two lines of code. The `Debug.Print` lines must be pasted below the second line and directly above the line `p = StrComp(...` The blank lines appearing in the sorted range may be blanks found in the SortClm. The code assumes that all rows are filled with data (no blanks) and all columns being of equal length. If this isn't the case the format of the data must be known before code can be adjusted.

Comment: Did you say you want a copy of the excel document? If so, how can I send it?

Comment: Also, there are names which do repeat in the same column. Those same names may repeat one or more times in the following  data column /s.  If they do not repeat that is where I would like the blank rows to see somebody is missing and track them back.

Comment: Oh by the way. My slow response is because I got a lot of things to do during working hours, and after work I got a baby to watch every second until he goes to bed.

Comment: There are many sites where you can upload files and email a link for someone else to download, usually within a few days' time. Google for the service you like and post the link here.

Comment: How about this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PL_YGFWATytuc31EJogpPM9Enh-NA7_k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, Google is one of the places I can't access from where I am right now. Same for DropBox. I tried to access WeTransfer.com just now and it seemed to work. You might try that.